# How to sort categories alphabetically with liquid?

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to sort post categories alphabetically rather than chronologically in Jekyll. Each attempt I make to do so results in string to integer errors. Any suggestions?

```
<div>
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <div class="archive-group">
    {% capture category_name %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %}

    <div id="#{{ category_name | slugize }}"></div>

    <h3 class="category-head"><small>{{ category_name }}</small></h3>
    <a name="{{ category_name | slugize }}"></a>

    {% for post in site.categories[category_name] %}
    <article class="archive-item">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}{% if post.link %}<span class="link-arrow"> &rarr;</span>{% endif %}</a>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jekyll [sort](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) filter

```
{% assign categories = site.categories | sort %}
{% for category in categories %}
...
```

Comment: I have tried that and it has zero affect, not sure why that is.

Comment: Repository url ?

Comment: It's a private repo but the necessary categories.html file is referenced in the code block of the original post. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: I apologize, your initial answer did solve my issue. I was running into a problem from using post. instead of site. Thank you kindly!